# Using Presigned url to upload an image to Amazon S3 in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to Amazon S3.

I’ve a piece of code where the file is getting uploaded to Amazon S3 in C# (.Net Framework) using Token and Secret key.

Now my requirements have changed and I've to use PreSigned url to upload the same Image/file. I'm able to generate a Presigned url but don't know how to upload the image using this PreSigned url. I tried to google but couldn't find the actual solution. Please see the below piece of code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method uploads files to a folder inside the Amazon Bucket
/// </summary>
/// <param name="BucketName">Amazon Bucket</param>
/// <param name="folderName">Name of the folder to be created</param>
/// <param name="fileName">Name of the file to be uploaded inside the folder</param>
/// <param name="fileUrl">Path of the file to be uploaded inside the folder</param>
/// <returns>Returns Amazon file path as BucketName/FolderName only if the file is successfully uploaded to this folder or else returns 1 to indicate that file upload was unsuccessful</returns>
public String CreateNewFileInFolder(String BucketName, String folderName, String fileName, String fileUrl, bool StoreInParentFolder = false, string PreSignurl)
{
    try
    {

        String S3Key = new S3FileInfo(
            s3Client, 
            BucketName, 
            folderName + "/" + fileName).Exists ? Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileUrl) + "-" + Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(fileUrl) : Path.GetFileName(fileUrl);

        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
        { 
            BucketName = BucketName, 
            Key = folderName + "/" + S3Key, 
            FilePath = fileUrl, 
            ContentType = GetContentType(fileName) 
        };
        s3Client.PutObject(request);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the exactly same thing recently. You would need to call the PreSignedUrl with PUT request that contains the image file stream. The below is my code for that.

```
private static async Task UploadToS3(string filename, string preSignedUrl)
{
    await using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
    var fileStreamResponse = await new HttpClient().PutAsync(
        new Uri(preSignedUrl),
        new StreamContent(fileStream));
    fileStreamResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to use AWS SDK to upload files with a PreSignedUrl instead of using HttpClient?

Comment: Try this [Niroshana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2388635/niroshana),
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_GetPreSignedURL.htm

Comment: They also have used HttpWebRequest in the GetContents method.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get your question. [Niroshana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2388635/niroshana)